# Javascript array used to calculate numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text file with the line:
Numbers (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)

I'm using the line below to read the numbers in parentheses off of the text file line. Numbers above.

```
output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /numbers/).join("\n").replace(/[^0-9.,]/g,'');
```

Then I'm trying to divide the numbers read by 2 with the line below

```
var array = [output];
divBy2 = v => parseInt(v) / 2;
result = array.map(divBy2);
```

Then I need to print the result of the array calculation using the line below.

```
document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML= result;
```

But it only returns the first number which is 1 / 2 = 0.5

Need help please.

Comment: [`'Numbers (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)'.replace(/Numbers\s*/, '').replace(/\((\d+),(\d+)\)/g, (m, $1, $2) => $1 / $2);`](https://jsfiddle.net/g08rtgfm/) and with [`toFixed(2)`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/g08rtgfm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

**[`Demo regex`](https://regex101.com/r/xbsrrH/3/)**

```js
function cal(str){
return str.toString().replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/g,"").replace(/\((\d+),(\d+)\)/g , (a,b,c)=> (b/c));
}

console.log(cal('Numbers (4,5),(3,2)'));
console.log(cal('Numbers (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)'));
```

Comment: line in text file with: Numbers (1,2),(3,4),(5,6) is not a fixed line and numbers will vary. They can change to: Numbers (4,5),(3,2), for example

Comment: @Fam see my updated answer .You could pass the string with in function